# Contract Factory Deploy Function Variables

Tags: solidity, web3js, contract-development, etherjs

I noticed you can actually put 3 arg into the deploy functions

```
.deploy(0,0,0)
```

min 3 , what is the purpose of the 3 variables. I. can't seem to find it on the documentation

Documentation Reference : https://docs.ethers.io/v5/api/contract/contract-factory/

```
let factory = new ethers.ContractFactory(abi, bytecode, signer);
let contract = await factory.deploy(0,0,0);
await contract.deployed()
```

I tried this and it's returning 0 fees on metamask tx

```
    const deployedContract = await factory.deploy(tokenURI, maxQuantity, cost, {
  gasLimit: 2,
  gasPrice: ethers.utils.parseUnits(price, price_unit),
})
```

Comment: Please share your constrat's constructor.

Answer (score -1):

These argument seem to be the contract constructor's arguments. Indeed, from the documentation:

```
contractFactory.deploy( ...args [ , overrides ] )
```

And, from their example:

```
const abi = [
  "constructor(address owner, uint256 initialValue)",
  "function value() view returns (uint)"
];
// other stuff
contract = await factory.deploy("ricmoo.eth", 42);
```

Notice that the ABI specifies two arguments, the `owner` (`address`) and the `initialValue` (`uint`), and the `deploy` function provides two arguments, a string* and an integer.

So, back to your question about deploy(0,0,0), it seems to correspond to three integers that should be declared in your contract's constructor.

Or I am completely wrong and it refers to this:

> If the optional overrides is specified, they can be used to override
> the endowment value, transaction nonce, gasLimit or gasPrice.

*I am not sure about that one, but it seems that this string refers to an address.

Comment: I tried ("ricmoo.eth", 42), it wont work, it needs 3 ("ricmoo.eth", 42, another random number)

Comment: ALso, the ABI you posted, is actually for 
factory = new ContractFactory(abi, bytecode, signer) which i already have a value for